Choice of spacetime foliation while quantising a conformal field theory
I was reading Rychkov's EPFL lectures on $D\geq 3$ CFT (along with these set of TASI lectures) and in chapter 3, he starts discussing radial quantisation and OPE (operator product expansion).  I understand that a choice of spacetime foliation gives us a `time coordinate' and therefore a quantisation resulting in a Hilbert space.
However, I don't understand how each `slice' gets its own Hilbert space. Prior to this, I thought that the entire spacetime had just one Hilbert space associated with it. Can someone explain? To be honest, this entire concept is causing a lot of confusion for me so it would greatly help if someone broke it down to pieces for me.

A Hilbert space is assigned to a foliation of the manifold. More precisely, we assign a Hilbert space to every slice in the foliation. The Hilbert spaces on two different slices in the same foliation are unitarily equivalent.
For example, we can foliate ${\mathbb R}^d$, into non-compact slices ${\mathbb R}^{d-1} \times {\mathbb R}_t$ or into compact slices as ${\mathbb S}^{d-1}\times {\mathbb R}_r$. The two foliations have completely different Hilbert spaces (one has a discrete spectrum, and the other has a continuous one).
In the study of CFTs, it is usual to consider the radial foliation ${\mathbb S}^{d-1}\times {\mathbb R}_r$ of ${\mathbb R}^d$ (because this is the foliation that is naturally related via Weyl transformations to usual time-evolution on the cylinder).

I don't think it is right to assign Hilbert spaces to foliations. Rather, they are assigned to concrete time slices. The spectrum is assigned to an operator, not a Hilbert space. The Hilbert spaces for both foliations you describe are the same (assuming conformal boundary conditions at infinity), and both have natural operators with discrete or continuous spectra.

I think a foliation by itself gives you just that -- a unitary equivalence between Hilbert spaces on different slices. It doesn't even give you a good Hamiltonian operator unless there is some other way (e.g. a symmetry) to relate these spaces (so that you can compose the two and get an operator on just one Hilbert space, rather than an operator between Hilbert spaces).
